# Eclipse not starting after hanging

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

My eclipse was working till now. After installing new software in the eclipse, it closed down and whenever I try to restart it, a dialog box appears saying:-

An error has occurred. See the log file in Workspace.metadata.log.

For the log file. please visit:-

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6ZcK0Ed_jdCMFA2RjBPUGdjeHM/edit?usp=sharing

Can any one tell me how to resolve this issue.

I know that I have the option to install Eclipse again. But I want to know is there any other way other then reinstalling?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some of the sub-components in the eclipse directory have been corrupted, possibly during an update or forced close of eclipse. You probably are best reinstalling it (point at the same workspace and you will only lose your preferences- better than losing everything! If you are using Java EE you may lose the servers depending on whether they are stored in workspace or in eclipse).

If you dont want to reinstall, you could try copying the plugins folder from a fresh copy over the existing folder. Then start eclipse with the -clean option

Edit: If you have updated anything, make sure it is for the correct version of Eclipse- wrong versions of plugins/updates can cause this kind of problem.